# using activemq failover URI for reconnecting, while timeout on first connection

Tags: java, activemq-classic, failover

I am currently using activemq failover uir for client reconnecting to the broker, and I also don't
want "send" operation to be blocked when it disconnect, so I am using URI like`failover:(tcp://192.168.193.177:61616)?timeout=1`, while the problem is if I can't get connection for the first time, the connecting will time out and the reconnecting doesn't work, the exception I got:

> Dec 7, 2011 3:39:28 PM org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport oneway
>     INFO: Failover timed out after 2ms
>     Dec 7, 2011 3:39:28 PM org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport doReconnect
>     INFO: Successfully connected to tcp://127.0.0.1:61616
>     Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-2" java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at com.cicc.mdf.dataserver.messaging.JMSMessagePublisher.publish(JMSMessagePublisher.java:197)
>           at com.cicc.mdf.dataserver.messaging.JMSMessagePublisher.publishRealTimeData(JMSMessagePublisher.java:270)
>           at com.cicc.mdf.dataserver.service.MarketDataService.process(MarketDataService.java:984)
>           at com.cicc.mdf.message.parser.BroadcastMessageParser.parseElement(BroadcastMessageParser.java:219)
>           at com.cicc.mdf.connectivity.RawDataParser.slice(RawDataParser.java:433)
>           at com.cicc.mdf.connectivity.RawDataParser.run(RawDataParser.java:110)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)

I thought the timeout parameter only works on send operation without interfere with reconnecting, but the first connecting?

EDIT: if the java client connected to the broker successfully for the first time, then if connection got disconnected, send operation will time out when connection don't established, and java client will reconnect to the broker, that what i am expected. 
    while if java client can't connect to the broker successfully for the first time, the connecting will time out, not trying to reconnect till successfully that what i am unexpected, am I some place wrong?

EDIT: Activemq version: 5.3.0

EDIT: Sorry, the URI is valid, it's my mistake, I was confused by another exception

any idea?

Thanks

ps: this is my first time on Stackoverflow, any unconventional behalve, pls correct it

Answer (score 0):

Your URI seems valid. Can you explain maybe what do you mean by "the reconnecting doesn't work"? Might it be that the exponential back off increases so much you think it doesn't reconnect?

You can disable it and try again:

```
failover:(tcp://localhost:61616)?useExponentialBackOff=false
```

Please include a bit of logs of your client, we might get more information on why the reconnecting doesn't work.
What is the ActiveMQ client you are using? Java? C++? C#?

Comment: Hey Srodriguez, if the java client can get connection for the first time, everything is expected, while if not, the client will not trying to reconnect to the broker, and get exception say  ""Failover timed out after 2ms"