# ActiveMQ FailoverTransport reconnecting too fast on Linux compared to Windows

Tags: java, linux, activemq-classic

I have one ActiveMQ broker on my Linux machine and a standalone Java application that acts as a producer running on my Windows machine. Both Windows and Linux machines are using the same version of Java 7.

I specify my broker url to be:

```
failover://(tcp://10.0.112.49:61616)?timeout=1000&warnAfterReconnectAttempts=1&maxReconnectAttempts=0`
```

Windows scenario: 
I start my application and it automatically connects to the ActiveMQ broker. When I stop the broker, the FailoverTransport tries to reconnect every second.

> 2015-07-16 15:14:52,737 ERROR [ActiveMQ Task-1]
>   (FailoverTransport.java:1099) CSN: Failed to connect to
>   [tcp://10.0.112.49:61616] after: 1 attempt(s)

This is the expected behavior.

However, when I run the application on Linux, instead of trying to reconnect every second, it reconnects every 5-10 milliseconds! I was wondering why the behavior is different.

Comment: Have you checked documentation to confirm that they both are reading the value as milliseconds? (Rather than windows reading it as milliseconds and linux reading it as microseconds.)

Comment: Documentation doesn't say much.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you don't understand `timeout` option. Here is what [documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/failover-transport-reference.html) says

> timeout
>
> Enables timeout on send operations (in miliseconds) without interruption of reconnection process

However in [Configuring ActiveMQ-CPP](http://activemq.apache.org/cms/configuring.html) I think it described better (but still the same).

> timeout
>
> If a send is blocked waiting on a failed connection to reconnect how
>   long should it wait before failing the send, default is forever (-1).

If I have understand you, the options you want is `initialReconnectDelay`, `maxReconnectDelay` and `useExponentialBackOff`.

See also:

1. [How do I configure automatic reconnection](http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-configure-automatic-reconnection.html)
2. [How can I support
   auto reconnection](http://activemq.apache.org/how-can-i-support-auto-reconnection.html)
3. [using activemq failover URI for reconnecting, while timeout on first connection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8428131/4182275)

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with timeout since the producer has already disconnected from the broker. It's more of a reconnecting issue and I'm not sure you understood my problem.

When I run my application in Windows and it loses its ActiveMQ connection for some reason (e.g. ActiveMQ was stopped), the FailoverTransports reconnects every second. However, when I run my app in Linux, instead of reconnecting every second, it reconnects every 5-10 milliseconds.

Comment: @MiguelPortugal Well, from your question I have concluded that you have expected 1 second reconnection time because of `timeout=1000`, guess I was wrong. However, to be more precise my answer would be that you need to try other options I proposed in my answer.